# Build tools are installed, still node-gyp build fails

Tags: c++, node.js, npm, windows-build-tools

Honestly, this is not the first time I setup windows build tools but it's probably the first time I'm failing and this is driving me crazy.

It's important to say that this is a windows 7 x64 machine.

I've tried to:

- Install the build tools using `npm install --global windows-build-tools` in Administrative `PowerShell.exe`. For some reason, the installer gets stuck at "still waiting for installer log file". Then I came across https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/208 where I tried the two community suggestions:

[image]

1. Suggestion 1) - Same result
   `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015`
2. Suggestion 2) - Go a different output but still failing.

`npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0`

Could not install Visual Studio Build Tools.
Please find more details in the log files, which can be found at
C:\Users\admin.windows-build-tools

Here's the log file:
https://pastebin.com/BU7bqWRX

- Since I was using windows-nvm I decided to uninstall it to exclude the hypothesis that this could be a side effect generate by this tool. Turns out it's not because I got the same problem with the windows installer.

Build tools are installed an I can run `MSBuild.exe` from three different directories:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bi n`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

I even exported one of this paths in my %PATH% env variable.

[image]

I've tried to specify the msvs_version as follows:

- `npm config set msvs_version 2017` still no luck
- `npm config set msvs_version 2019` no luck

Here's the content of my `.npmrc`

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.4 node/v13.14.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\admin\.npmrc
msvs_version = "2019"

; globalconfig C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
python = "C:\\Users\\admin\\.windows-build-tools\\python27\\python.exe"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\admin
; HOME = C:\Users\admin
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

So, no matter what I do, every time npm installs a native module where `node-gyp` is required, I get the following error:

```
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2019
gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"
gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32106.194) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"

gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32106.194) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1585) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools
"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version does not match this VS Command Prompt or the
gyp ERR! find VS installation cannot be used.
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modu
les\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\
nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\dev\test-app\node_modules\firebird
gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: `Failed attempt to download URL: 'bits://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=1F0C5812581EFDCA1A2A9C3BCE802F53D7832D6E' to: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\{a9528995-e130-4501-ae19-bbfaddb779cc}\Msi_BuildTools_MSBuild_amd64'` seems likely to be the cause of the build tools failing to install. Have you tried installing them manually?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion Alan but still didn't work .That file no longer exists. 
Also tried to use chocolatey to accomplish the task without luck. Since this was getting very frustrating I solved the issue by migrating to windows 10 (node-gyp + builds tools are now working as expected.

Comment: Ah, hadn't spotted you were using an OS that hasn't been supported by MS for 2 years, probably explains your issues

Comment: I cant believe you havent gotten a single answer to this... Ugh